# how to find complete set modulo of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would you go about finding the complete modulo set of $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$?  I can see $0,1,2,x+1,x-1$ are zero divisors
but am a little confused on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the set equivalent to $0$, which is the ideal generated by $x^2-1$. This ideal $(x^2-1)$ is given by $\{r(x^2-1)|r \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]\}$. With this in mind, you can calculate which coset/equivalent class each polynomial belongs to by guessing for $r$, or simply using polynomial division.

Answer (score 1):

Any polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ can be written in a unique way as
$$
f(x)=(x^2-1)q(x)+ax+b
$$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_3$ and $q(x)\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$; obviously $f(x)\equiv ax+b\pmod{x^2-1}$. Moreover
$$
ax+b\equiv cx+d\pmod{x^2-1}
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
a=c\text{ and }b=d
$$
(prove it). Thus a complete representative set has nine elements.